# Link count on high PR website, which is better?

Tags: seo, pagerank

i have search this question for quite long but i cannot find the answer. may be because i don't know what keyword should i enter.

i wonder, which is better to have let say 100 link only one one website that have PR 9 than 1 link on every 100 website PR 9 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is flawed. Websites don't have PR, web pages. PR is per page, not per website.

Additionally, chasing PR is a huge waste of time. I'd rather have 100 links on low PR pages that are related to my website and rank well for the terms I want to rank well for, than high PR links from unrelated websites. PR has very little weight in Google's ranking algorithm but links from relevant websites do make a difference and are what you're really looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking which is better to have 100 links on a domain which has a home page of PR9. Or is it better to have 100 links for unique sites with a home page PR9?

Either way there is much more being taken into account. The link is it dofollow or nofollow? The page which the link is on is it cached? Are you attempting to get a link in a forum profile who's home page is PR9 if so that does you no good.

There are few PR9 sites, and getting links from them doesn't mean much unless you are on the home page or a few links from the home page with a dofollow contextual link preferably.

It's not worth your time trying to build links from domains which have a high PR on the home page because chances are you won't get a valuable link from them.

Comment: yes, which better 100 link in one domain like forum (http://blabla.com/forum) or 100 link on unique site with PR9. every link is do follow.

Comment: why link on forum is no good? i read every article. everyone said that is a good trick.

Comment: I had a feeling that's what you were referring to. High PR forum home pages people try and get links from user profiles. The profiles don't always get indexed and what relevance and authority does a profile page have? Forum links are fine if the page the link is on is at least cached and the link is relevant to the pages content.The more PR on the link page the better, and of course a dofollow.

Comment: I would rather get 100 links from unique sites. I think at some point the value of your links go down the more you have from the same domain. Though the size of the site i'm sure plays a roll and more. But I would not want 100 sig links on one forum especially since the majority would not be relevant.

Comment: yes you are right, i just read youtube video about this question. 1 link on 1 IP. yes what i say, not about profile page. but something like forum signature or post on a forum board.

Comment: If this answer was helpful you can mark it as the answer. Good luck with your link building.

Answer (score 0):

John's and Anagio's answers are more complete, they are not trying to avoid your question, but simply make you think that SEO is not a black or white answer.

But i don't want to leave a bitter taste in your mouth, so IMHO supposing:

- that both types of links are **NOT `nofollow`**
- that the pages cotaining those links do not contain another tons of links to *all of crap sites*, but just or mainly the link to your page.
- that the contents of the pages containing those links do have some relation to your site content, or at least the link itself to your site is displaied with a brief description explaing what your site is about.

Supposing all of the above, I would go for the incoming link from a PR9 page, expecially considering that the only PR9 page I saw so far is Google itself home page. So I would say that a link from Google home page to your site would both bring you a lot of traffic and also a lot of PR would flow into your site.

Moreover if you are just comparing pure numbers the PR is supposed to be on an exponenetial scale, in other words if we could suppose that a page get PR1 when it has 10 incoming links, it does not mean that the same page needs 20 links to reach a PR2, but more probably it would need 100 links, a PR3 might require 1000 links to that page, and so on.
Therefor guess the number of links needed by a page to make it reach a PR9: much more than 100!!!

So it also makes sense that one link from a PR9 page brings you something more that 100 links from PR1 pages, cause the effort to push a page to PR9 is much bigger than simply getting 100 incoming links from PR1 pages.